# How can i perform mongodb findAndModify only for first matched document?

Tags: mongodb

I need to find and modify first matched element using mongodb. Is it possible? I failed to find how to do it from official doc: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command

There is not findAndModifyOne method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to the docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) "This command can be used to atomically modify a document (**at most one**) and return it." (emphasis mine)

**Edit:** If you use the `sort` argument to `findAndModify`, then it will operate on the first result found according to the sort criteria.

Comment: My query cannot limit result to single document, but I need to update only first document.

Comment: @Alexey, it will only modify the first document. All others will be unmodified. That is, it does what you want.

Comment: Seems that i have incorrectly translate "at most once". English is not my native language. Thanks mstearn.

Comment: It is also true with `MongoTemplate` too although the api doc said `Update on documents matching Criteria of given Query` (u can go deep into source code and find they use `executeFindOneInternal`)

Comment: Thanks @kidnan1991 this was my confusion. That doc needs to be updated!